# Why are DEBUG and TRACE messages printed when only INFO messages should be printed?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a very simple setup here. I want only the INFO messages to appear in the console. DEBUG and TRACE should only appear in the file. Why do I still have all messages in the console?
This is the Output
[image]

Log4j2xmlFile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Properties>
    <Property name="basePath">target/logs</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${basePath}/${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/all.trace.log" filePattern="${basePath}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/all.trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable}{FATAL=Magenta, ERROR=Bright red, WARN=Yellow, INFO=Blue, DEBUG=Cyan, TRACE=Green}"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable}{FATAL=Magenta, ERROR=Bright red, WARN=Yellow, INFO=Blue, DEBUG=Cyan, TRACE=Green}" disableAnsi="false"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.example"  level="ALL" additivity="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"  level="ALL" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My Class

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     logger.debug("Hello debug");
     logger.info("Hello info");
     logger.trace("Hello trace");
 }
}
```

Output Console

```
2023-01-11T17:37:46,731 [main] DEBUG: Hello debug
2023-01-11T17:37:46,736 [main] INFO : Hello info
2023-01-11T17:37:46,736 [main] TRACE: Hello trace
```

Output File

```
2023-01-11T17:37:46,731 [main] DEBUG: Hello debug
2023-01-11T17:37:46,736 [main] INFO : Hello info
2023-01-11T17:37:46,736 [main] TRACE: Hello trace
```

Comment: Your root logger config defines the log level to be INFO but the "child" logger config for "org.example" locally changes that to ALL. That means all loggers have INFO level except those for "org.example" and its children. You should also see all log statements on the console but only those for "org.example" in your file due to appenders being inherited (i.e. the "org.example" file appender is added to the list, it doesn't replace the list). Reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html

Comment: But that is exactly what I want to achieve. In the console only the info messages should appear, and in the file all. Why do the INFO messages appear in the console although it has the level INFO. Actually this should be prevented?I see the same log statements in the file and console

Comment: Read my comment again and also the page I linked. There are 2 things in your configuration: logger configs and appenders. As I wrote the level in the logger config overrides the one of the root logger so all loggers that use it emit _all_ severities. Appenders are combined so the more specific logger has both - as described by the Log4j architecture. I assume what you're really after are appender thresholds, i.e. you'd define on the appender or appender ref what log levels to accept, e.g. `<AppenderRef ref="Console" level="INFO"/>`

Comment: Sorry, I read through the page. I understood now that loggers and root are added and NOT replaced. However, I still do not understand why a TRACE message appears in the console. The ROOT level should filter for INFO and therefore ignore TRACE. The file and the console have exactly the same output

Comment: When you log a message the log level filtering is performed only **once** (so root's level is not checked). To check the level every time a message is handed over to a parent logger, you can use a [`ThresholdFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter) inside the `<Logger>` and `<Root>` elements.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. I have never read somewhere. But now it makes sense

Comment: Also, as I tried to explain above, the TRACE seems to be originating from the "org.example" logger or one if its children so they forward _all_ messages to the appenders. So you need to filter either at the appender ref level or use the threshold filter Piotr suggested.

Comment: Thank you for writing again. I thought I understood the inheritance in the logger. I still don't understand why the ROOT logger sends something to the Appenders, although its level is clearly limited to INFO. First comes the org.example and after that the ROOT level